# How to get sqlite3 into Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, debugging, sqlite, galaxy-tab

I successfully rooted my Galaxy Tab and now I'd like to debug a SQLite database of my application using sqlite3 command on the device but it is not available there.

Is there any way how to install/inject this tool to the device, please?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You might check out this link:http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Thank you. Although this blog is quite unrelated to the question, the link in the end of discussion pointed me to an idea that I can download the database to PC, modify it there and then upload it back to the device. It's not perfect but I can live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rooted on your galaxy tab, you can install Busybox, Connectbot and Terminal IDE from the Samsung Market, then you can install linux (i.e. google "sourceforge linux on android") which is packaged with python. I am running unbuntu 12 precise from sourceforge on my galaxy tab 10.1. Ubuntu12.04 beta comes with both python 2.7 and python 3.2.2. Python can implement sqlite3.